# How to properly get InputStreamResource to ResponseEntity in Webflux?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a method that fetches a PDF from another web service, but we have to fetch a cross reference ID before we can make the call:

**PdfService.groovy**

```
@Service
class PdfService {
  @Autowired
  WebClient webClient

  @Autowired
  CrossRefService crossRefService

  InputStreamResource getPdf(String userId, String pdfId) {
      def pdf = return crossRefService
                .getCrossRefId(userId)
                .flatMapMany(crossRefResponse -> {
                    return webClient
                                .get()
                                .uri("https://some-url/${pdfId}.pdf", {
                                    it.queryParam("crossRefId", crossRefResponse.id)
                                    it.build(pdfId)
                                 })
                                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                                .retrieve()
                                .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer)                            
                })
                
        convertDataBufferToInputStreamResource(pdf)    
  }

  // https://manhtai.github.io/posts/flux-databuffer-to-inputstream/
  InputStreamResource getInputStreamFromFluxDataBuffer(Flux<DataBuffer> data) throws IOException {
    PipedOutputStream osPipe = new PipedOutputStream();
    PipedInputStream isPipe = new PipedInputStream(osPipe);

    DataBufferUtils.write(data, osPipe)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                try {
                    osPipe.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }
            })
            .subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer());


    new InputStreamResource(isPipe);
    }
}
```

**PdfController.groovy**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/pdf/{pdfId}.pdf")
class PdfController {
    
    @Autowired
    PdfService service

    @GetMapping
    Mono<ResponseEntity<Resource>> getPdf(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt jwt, @PathVariable String pdfId) {
        def pdf = service.getPdf(jwt.claims.userId, pdfId)
        Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok().body(pdf))
    }
}
```

When I run my service class as an integration test, everything work fine, and the `InputStreamResource` has a content length of 240,000.  However, when I try to make this same call from the controller, it seems as if the internal cross reference call is never made.

What is the correct way to place an `InputStreamResource` into a `Publisher`?  Or is it even needed?

Comment: Better to use `doFinally` instead of `doOnComplete`